# macOS: trying to run python program in terminal it is not printing anything

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying to print this code and everytime I run it in terminal it does not display anything.
Could someone help explain why it's not working?
it must contain these two methods:
countRepetitions that takes a ciphertext as an argument and returns the total number of repetitions between all 16-byte blocks
detectECBMode that takes a ciphertext as input, determines if any repetitions occur, and returns a Boolean value indicating if the ciphertext was encrypted using ECB mode
I am trying to get the program to read the ciphertext and then print the ECB encrypted ciphertext encoded in the hexadecimal format followed by the number of repetition.
[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmOKT.png)

this is my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from collections import Counter

def countRepetitions(ciphertext):
    blocks = [ciphertext[i:i+16] for i in range(0, len(ciphertext), 16)]
    return sum(count-1 for count in Counter(blocks).values())

def detectECBMode(ciphertext):
    blocks = [ciphertext[i:i+16] for i in range(0, len(ciphertext), 16)]
    return len(blocks) != len(set(blocks))

# Open the file and read all the lines
with open('ciphertexts.txt', 'r') as f:
    ciphertexts = [line.strip() for line in f]

# Iterate over each ciphertext and check if it was encrypted using ECB mode
for ciphertext in ciphertexts:
    if detectECBMode(ciphertext):
        repetitions = countRepetitions(ciphertext)
        print(f"Ciphertext in ECB mode -{ciphertext}")
        print(f"Repetitions - {repetitions}")
        break  # Stop after finding the first ciphertext encrypted using ECB mode
```

[this is the output im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqPqz.png)

Comment: i meant to put a separation between countRepetitions and dectectECBMode

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: Put some `print` statements in your code to check that what you expect to be there actually is there. For example, what is the content of `ciphertexts`?